# Deny access to files directory of cakephp 2.4.2 through url

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I am using cakephp 2.4.2 to develop a web application. I am looking for a  proper way of disallowing viewers from accessing the files directory that lies inside webroot. Techniques other than the  .htaccess file configuration are appreciable. I would like to know if there is any cakephp code that may help to solve the problem.

Comment: What's wrong with .htaccess?

Comment: The term 'viewers' refers to unregistered users

Comment: I would like to know if there is any other way

Comment: maybe some better way other than that

Comment: You could place your files somewhere else and then use `CakeResponse::file()`, see http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#cake-response-file

Comment: @TikaramBhandari Viewers actually being unregistered users, that's the kind of info that should be in your question in the first place.